# Cómo hacer un ⇒ (condicional, conectivo lógico)?

Tags: javascript, operador

Estoy intentando evaluar este string:

```
var proposicion = "(true&&false)⇒!true";
console.log(eval(proposicion));
```

pero no funciona porque el caracter "⇒" es un conectivo lógico no reconocido.

tengo esta función que me retorna el valor de verdad entre dos valores según las reglas del conectivo "⇒".

```
function Condicional(v1,v2){
    return (!v1)||v2;               //fórmula de la condicional
}
```

Y puedo aplicarla para el string en cuestión de esta forma:

```
var proposicion = "(true&&false)⇒!true";
var pars = proposicion.split("⇒")
var result = Condicional(eval(pars[0]),eval(pars[1]))
console.log(result)
```

Y funciona, pero cómo puedo hacer que funcione para cualquier otro tipo de proposición? por ejemplo:

```
var proposicion2 = "((true⇒false)&&false)⇒false===true||!false"
```

o cualquier otra?

Comment: Tienes que construir un parser de lo que vas a evaluar. No puedes asumir que JavaScript va a ejecutar tu código tal cual.

Comment: No sólo haría falta construir un parser como comenta Luiggi, además deberías definir un orden de precedencia dentro de los operadores de javascript.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva me podrías decir cómo o dónde hacerlo? dónde tendría que ir para definir ese orden de precedencia?

Comment: En la lógica del parser. Deberás decidir por ejemplo si "a || b => c && d" equivale a "a || (b => c) && d", o a "a || (b => c && d)", o a "(a || b) => (c && d)". Una vez que tengas claro esto podrás implementar la lógica de tu parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en lugar de usar ⇒ usas la funcion `Condicional()` cuando armas el string que evaluas

```js
function Condicional(v1,v2){
    return (!v1)||v2;              
}


var proposicion = "Condicional((true&&false),!true)";

var result1 = eval(proposicion);

alert("Condicion1: " + result1);



var proposicion2 = "Condicional(((Condicional(true,false))&&false), false===true||!false)";

var result2 = eval(proposicion2);

alert("Condicion2: " + result2);
```

Sino se me ocurre evaluar librerias que permitan parsear expresiones, como ser

[nerdamer](http://nerdamer.com/)

veras que puedes definir operaciones custom, analiza la documentacion el titulo "EXTENDING THE CORE", podrias ver de definir uan expresion con el operador ⇒ (aunque hay que ver si toma ese caracter)

Comment: Gracias, por ahí va la cosa, solo que según las reglas de la lógica proposicional esa proposición específica: var proposicion2 = "((true⇒false)&&false)⇒false===true||!false"  quedaría así:

var proposicion2 = "Condicional((Condicional(true,false)&&false),false)===(true||!false)"

Aunque de todas formas si me llega otra proposición distinta a esa, tendría que buscar cómo distinguir bien eso para aplicarlo, quizás con recursividad pero aún no logro mentalizarlo, ya que necesito evaluar cualquier proposición que me venga.

Comment: Yo tengo duda, al final debería quedar asi: `eval(eval(eval(true,false),"&&false"),"false===true||!false)`